# Do pyrosomes reproduce by ways other than cloning?

Tags: zoology, reproduction, marine-biology

I know that Pyrosomes are large colonies of floating tube-like animals that live in the sea, particularly in the tropics. They are just like any type of free floaters

I know  that pyrosomes can reproduce by [cloning](http://www.deepseanews.com/2013/08/the-60-foot-long-jet-powered-animal-youve-probably-never-heard-of]/), but are there any other ways that they can reproduce?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: Please provide a link reference in your question where I have inserted [reference required]. "I know for a fact" is not appropriate here, because it does not provide the means for readers (such as myself) to check the background to a question.

Comment: Yes. sexual reproduction. From a <1min google search: "Pyrosomes make both eggs and sperm... alternating asexual and sexual reproduction results in giant swarms of pyrosome colonies." We ask that you do your own research before asking questions on Bio.SE. Please update your question with some indication you've done prior research to avoid having it downvoted/closed. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on writing good questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed pyrosomes use a very interesting form of reproduction. They actually use both sexual and asexual form of reproduction each time they reproduce. Pyrosomes, which are colonial tunicates, produce both egg and sperm. In each pyrosome of a colony, a single egg is fertilized and develops into a 4-staged animal. This form leaves the parent body and starts forming its own colony. It does so using the process called budding, which rapidly develops a new colony of pyrosomes. You can see [here](http://eol.org/pages/10779/details), [here](http://oceana.org/marine-life/corals-and-other-invertebrates/giant-pyrosome) or [here](http://animals.jrank.org/pages/1651/Salps-Thaliacea-PYROSOME-Pyrosoma-atlanticum-SPECIES-ACCOUNTS.html) for more information.

[image: pyrosome reproduction][source](http://www.mer-littoral.org/32/thaliacea-3.php) (in french though ;)